# Unity (2018.4.13.F1), C#, Coroutine does not follow "waitforSeconds", it's 3 to 5x faster

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm an advanced beginner. I encountered a problem in one of my coroutines, and I can't figure out the problem. I have a script (one class), that has two coroutines, please take a look at the pastebin. Both are created with "yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f)".... While the first one "CreatePowerOutput()" works as intended (engine core refilling a capacitor constantly), and is always active, the second one "RechargeShield()" is called specifically when needed (and requires energy from capacitor while doing so), but is executing 3 to 5 times faster than it should, ignoring the given 0.1f seconds. I fail to understand why that happens, I don't see the issue here.

Important : I checked thoroughly, the Coroutine RechargeShield() is definitly only active ONE at the time (parallel to CreatePowerOutput() ), no second instance of the same coroutine is running, it's definitly faster and ignoring the wait time, the while loop does not wait 0.1f seconds. The control variable is also working as it should, checked that too.

Is there a problem with using multiple coroutines in a script/class ? I don't know this, though I never heard about that. I would be really happy if someone could maybe point out the problem for me in the Coroutine "RechargeShield()". Thanks in advance.

```
*void Update()
    {
    capacitorSlider.value = currentPowerCapacitor;
    shieldSlider.value = currentShieldHP;

    if (!rechargeModeActive && (currentShieldHP < maxShieldHP))
            {
            Debug.Log("True");
            StartCoroutine(RechargeShield());
            }
    else if(rechargeModeActive && (currentShieldHP >= maxShieldHP))
            {
            Debug.Log("False");
            StopCoroutine(RechargeShield());
            rechargeModeActive = false;
            }
    else if(rechargeModeActive && (currentShieldHP<maxShieldHP))
            {
            //do nothing, recharge already running
            }
    else
            {
            Debug.Log("nothing");
            //do nothing, this should trigger when !rechargeModeActive && (currentShieldHP = maxShieldHP)
            }
       
    }


//===================Coroutines========================

    private IEnumerator RechargeShield()
        {
        rechargeModeActive = true;
        while (shieldGeneratorToggle.isOn)
            {
            if (rechargeModeActive)
                {
                float shieldRechargeValue = hpRestored/10;
                float shieldRechargePowerValue = rechargePowerReq_Shield/10;
                currentShieldHP += shieldRechargeValue;
                DepleteCapacitor(shieldRechargePowerValue);
                Debug.Log("Shield recharged with " +shieldRechargeValue);
                if (currentShieldHP > maxShieldHP)
                    {
                    currentShieldHP = maxShieldHP;
                    }
                }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }

//=====================Working Coroutine for Comparision=======================

    private IEnumerator CreatePowerOutput()
        {
        while(engineCoreToggle.isOn)
            {
            float basicEnergyDrawValue = basicEnergyNeed/10;
            float reloadValue = powerOutputSecond/10;
            ChargeCapacitor(reloadValue);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }*
```

Comment: Just a general note: Are your fields `basicEnergyNeed`, `powerOutputSecond` etc all`float`? Otherwise you have integer divisions `/10` ... in general just to be sure I would always rather use `/10f` in such cases

Comment: And how exactly do you ensure that `the Coroutine RechargeShield() is definitly only active ONE at the time` ? And are you playing with the `Time.timeScale` somewhere? `WaitForSeconds` depends on it .. if this is not desired rather use `WaitForSecondsRealtime`

Comment: Hi. Yes, they are all float. As for the control, the variable "rechargeModeActive" takes care of it. Its initial value is False. It is set to TRUE inside the Coroutine, but before the While-Loop. It is set to false in the Update() function, the part where I call StopCoroutine. 

According to my Debug-Lines, the Coroutine is only called Once. The Update() method controls it (runs once per frame).

Comment: I added 10f to the calculations. It seems to run a bit slower now, but still twice as fast as the "CreatePowerOutput"... I am not manipulating Timescale anywhere, and also I'm not using Time.Deltatime anywhere, I thought it would not be necessary since I precisly order it to use 0.1 of a second.

Comment: WaitForSecondsRealtime made no change. I also tried to declare the WaitforSeconds at the beginning, instead of the "new" constructor below. Same result. RechargeShield() still runs twice as fast as it should.

Comment: Is it possible that in `StopCoroutine(RechargeShield());` you create a new `IEnumerator` so your running routine is never stopped? Have you tried to rather store in a field `Coroutine currentRecharge;` and assign to it `currentRecharge = StartCoroutine(Recharge shield());` and the later `if(currentRecharge != null) StopCoroutine (currentRecharge);`

Comment: You never stop the running coroutine.
You need to pass the value returned from StartCoroutine to StopCoroutine.